# Kubernetes javascript client - could not filter by label selector

Tags: javascript, kubernetes, kube-apiserver

I run the following function from Kubernetes official javascript client, for example :

```
.listNamespacedPod("default", null, "false", "smth=test", null, null, null, null, null, null)
```

or any other function.

There is a param called labels selector.

Now I would like to find the pods (as in the HTTP request) with the following label selector:

```
smth=test
```

But I cannot send `smth=test` as a string.

How can I filter by label selector?

This is my metadata from the YAML:

```
metadata:
  name: label-demo
  labels:
    smth: test 
    app: nginx
```

I can run via `kubectl`:

```
kubectl -n="namespace" get deployments -l=smth=test
```

so it will return only the matched labels.

Answer (score 5):

Based on [CoreV1API](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/master/src/gen/api/coreV1Api.ts) and [this sample](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/blob/ed1e579d189c727937df65897303434e2cd120fc/examples/typescript/informer/informer-with-label-selector.ts), it should be:

```
.listNamespacedPod("default", undefined, "false", undefined, undefined, "smth=test")
```

It will list all pods with labels `smth=test` in the `default` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

I wholeheartedly agree with the answer provided by Arnaud Develay but I wanted to add what I found out while investigating this question.

To make your code respond with the `Pods` that are having this label, it also needs to be included in the `spec.selector.matchLabels` (and `.spec.template. metadata.labels` respectively).

By using the following `Deployment` definition:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: label-demo
  labels:
    smth: test # <-- IMPORTANT
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      search: here 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        search: here 
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
```

and following code snippet from the official github page:

- *[Github.com: Kubernetes Client: Javascript](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript)*

```js
const k8s = require('@kubernetes/client-node');

const kc = new k8s.KubeConfig();
kc.loadFromDefault();

const k8sApi = kc.makeApiClient(k8s.CoreV1Api);


k8sApi.listNamespacedPod("default", undefined, "false", undefined, undefined, "smth=test").then((res) => {
    console.log(res.body);
});
```

The code generated following output (and empty list of `Pods`):

```js
V1PodList {
  apiVersion: 'v1',
  items: [],
  kind: 'PodList',
  metadata: V1ListMeta {
    _continue: undefined,
    remainingItemCount: undefined,
    resourceVersion: '990955',
    selfLink: '/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods'
  }
}
```

While querying with the `search=here` label in the `.spec` responded with:

```js
V1PodList {
  apiVersion: 'v1',
  items: [
    V1Pod {
      apiVersion: undefined,
      kind: undefined,
      metadata: [V1ObjectMeta],
      spec: [V1PodSpec],
      status: [V1PodStatus]
    }
  ],
  kind: 'PodList',
  metadata: V1ListMeta {
    _continue: undefined,
    remainingItemCount: undefined,
    resourceVersion: '991498',
    selfLink: '/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods'
  }
}
```